# With NDK, std::fstream open() is failing, whereas fopen() works correctly, Why?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, fstream

When I run following code:

```
char const * path = "/path/to/file";
std::fstream fs;
fs.open(path, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
if (!fsWave) {
    LOGE("open, Error opening file %s", path);
}
```

it prints the error log `open, Error opening file /path/to/file`

**But**, the following works smoothly:

```
FILE * pf = NULL;
if(NULL == (pf = fopen(path, "w+b"))) {
    LOGE("open, Error opening file %s", path);
}
```

By *smoothly*, I meant, it does not prints the error log and **does** create a file at specified location.

**Setup**

- Android Studio 2.2.1
- NDK 12.1.2977051
- Included permissions in manifest `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
- Test device - Samsung S6

What could be the reason, `fstream::open()` is failing?

Comment: General [in/out confusion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)? The `fopen` call has different semantics from your fstream version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C file API mode `"w+"` corresponds to the iostream [open mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) `in | out | trunc`, and not to `in | out`. The former creates a new file if it doesn't exist, the latter results in an error.

Comment: Thanks. And the `open mode` link was really helpful.